# How to write a simple .htaccess with two entry points

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have problem while trying to use below .htaccess file to direct my requests. every one begin with rest to rest.php and others to index.php. the problem is all request directed to index.php even the ones begin with rest. did i miss something ?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^rest(.+)$ rest.php? [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php? [QSA]
```

Comment: Can you please provide some URLs you try to call?

Comment: if its dev environment I would try to change the order of rule 1 and 2

Comment: http://localhost/myApp/

Comment: http://localhost/myApp/rest/to/endpoint

Comment: @talsibony i did changed the order and got the same result

Comment: You are probably missing that a) rewriting configured in .htaccess context always works as a “loop”, until none of your rules match any more, and that b) RewriteConds only affect the immediately following rule. So, your request gets written to `rest.php` first, then the “next round” starts - `rest.php` is a physically existing file, so your conditions make it skip the next rule. But `rest.php` matches the `^(.+)$` of the next rule perfectly fine, and so it gets rewritten to index.php

Comment: i read this question and do add https://serverfault.com/questions/241907/rewriterules-not-stopping-with-last-flag and try what did @ooshro suggest but also have the same issue :/

Answer (score -1):

below .htaccess seems to solve my problem, please if there is a bug, write it in comment.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^rest$ rest.php? [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^rest(.+)$ rest.php? [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php? [QSA]
```

Comment: we here for help each other, the guy who disliked the answer please give me a better solution if you have ...